# Passing one component to another in react.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a basic template for my page. I have an index.jsx file Where I am loading header and main-wrapper to the document body. header and main-wrapper have certain properties for page layout

```
'use strict'

var React = require('react')
var Header = require('./Header')
var MainWrapper = require('./MainWrapper')

React.renderComponent(<Header />, document.body)
React.renderComponent(<MainWrapper />, document.body)
```

Now MainWrapper may contain different components. So I have to pass components to main wrapper as argument.

**For eg:**

```
<MainWrapper component={SearchResults} queryText={this.state.queryText} />
```

where SearchResult is a component and queryText has to be accesiable in searchResult component

Is there any method to do this in react. Thanks in advance :) !

Answer (score 2):

You could pass them as children. Normally makes more sense for wrapper components to do it this way.

eg:

```
<MainWrapper>
    <SearchResults queryText=this.props.queryText />
</MainWrapper>
```

Then in MainWrappers Render:

```
render() {
    return <div>{ this.props.children }</div>;
}
```

That way MainWrapper doesnt need to know anything about the components, it just wraps them.

Answer (score 0):

In `MainWrapper`, you can use `cloneWithProps` in the `render` method to set properties:

```
var React = require('react/addons');

var MainWrapper = React.createClass({
    // ....

    render: function() {
        return React.addons.cloneWithProps(this.props.component,
                                           {queryText: this.props.queryText});
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working. the output on main wrapper is  React.addons.cloneWithProps(this.props.component, );

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `cloneWithProps` will return a component. What do you mean by 'the output on main wrapper'?

Comment: When I am passing <MainWrapper component={SearchResults} queryText={this.state.queryText} />  and trying to access {this.props.component} in main wrapper, error I am geting in the console is "cannot read ref of undefined property

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on. I don't think _component_ is a reserved prop name. Check in the debugger what's in `this.props` when you're in the `render` method of `MainWrapper`

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have to pass components as props, just require and render them inside your component, f.ex:

```
var MainWrapper = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var component
    if (someLogic)
      component = <SearchResults queryText={this.props.queryText} />
    return {component}
  }
})
```

My point here is that you do not need to pass them as arguments at all, you might as well require them and do the rendering logic *inside* the MainWrapper component. This would probably make the code less complex and more readable.

Comment: the problem is that, main wrapper can contain any component. In this case its seachResult, so I cant hard code it

Comment: @VamshiKolanu OK, but you can still do the logic inside the MainWrapper file. Passing dynamic components adds unnecessary complexity and will quickly become hard to follow.

Comment: Is there any better way to do it?. bcos I may have to pass videoshow page , audioshow page etc etc components to main wrapper.

Comment: @VamshiKolanu sure, but you will have to do the logic at some point. A common way is to map all your sections and pluck the one you need depending on the slug.